# How to get a Substring from a string in C# where the string has sequential numbers?

Tags: c#, collections, substring, calculation

I have a Name, Value pair both strings stored in a dictionary.

```
e.g.,

Name        |   Value   |
-------------------------
Dim1L9      |   10.98   |
-------------------------
Dim14L10    |   26.32   |
-------------------------   
Dim14L11    |   95.25   |
-------------------------
Dim1L10     |   9.99    |
```

From this table i would like to get the sum of Dim1
10.98 + 9.99 = 20.97.  How can i do this?

Comment: `data.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("Dim1L")).Sum(x => x.Value)`

Comment: Great. That works thanks.

Comment: @haim770 - you have given me a fresh perspective. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome

Comment: The Name is formed using the Dimension and Lane. There can be 10 Dimensions and 15 lanes.  Hence the text Dim1L9 implies Dimension 1 and Lane 9.  The user will fill a input parameter which the Dimension and would like a sum of values.  Hence the user will only pass Dim1 not Dim1L.  The above logic will not work.

Comment: @haim770 -- you should submit that as an answer instead of just a comment.

Comment: @haim770 - The Name is formed using the Dimension and Lane. There can be 10 Dimensions and 15 lanes. Hence the text Dim1L9 implies Dimension 1 and Lane 9. The user will fill a input parameter which the Dimension and would like a sum of values. Hence the user will only pass Dim1 not Dim1L. The above logic will not work.

Comment: @Abe can you update the question to better reflect the data shape and how it needs to be parsed based on your last comment?

Comment: @Abe, Determining whether a certain `KeyValuePair` in a dictionary is indeed a "Dimension 1" or "Lane9" better not be based on a shape of a simple `string`. If the above doesn't satisfy your needs, please add the relevant details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to get sum for all names:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)L\d+$");
var sumByDimension = from kvp in dictionary
            let match = regex.Match(kvp.Key)
            where match.Success
            group kvp by match.Groups[1].Value into g
            select new
            {
                Dimension = g.Key,
                Sum = g.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value)
            };
```

Output:

```
{ Dimension: "1", Sum: 20.97 }
{ Dimension: "14", Sum: 121.57}
```